# Bootstrap scrollspy does not work with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem. I have following HTML:

```
    <div id="scroll-nav">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="#somelink1">
             <div>text1</div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#somelink2">
             <div>text2</div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#somelink3">
             <div>text3</div>
            </a>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I also have following javascript:

`$('body').scrollspy({target: '#scroll-nav'});`

Scrollspy does not work, I do not get any JS errors. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the documentation says:

> Navbar links must have resolvable id targets. For example, a `<a href="#home">home</a>` must correspond to something in the DOM like `<div id="home"></div>`.

Comment: I have corresponding divs with id "somelink1", etc